# Implementing iterator in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I am saving the keys of the tree in an array by doing an inorder traversal on the tree.

I am using `counter` variable in the function `private void inOrder(Node node,K[] keys,int counter)` and add the keys to the array while incrementing the counter variable after each addition. The problem, however, is that because of recursion the value of `counter` is reset to 0. I also tried making `counter` static but it complicates the problem even more and doesn't solve it either.

Below is the full code.

```
package lab8;
import java.util.Set;

public interface Map61B<K, V> extends Iterable<K> {
    /** Removes all of the mappings from this map. */
    void clear();

    /* Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. */
    boolean containsKey(K key);

    /* Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this
     * map contains no mapping for the key. 
     */
    V get(K key);

    /* Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map. */
    int size();

    /* Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. */
    void put(K key, V value);

    /* Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. */
    Set<K> keySet();    

    /* Removes the mapping for the specified key from this map if present.
     * Not required for Lab 8. If you don't implement this, throw an 
     * UnsupportedOperationException. */
    V remove(K key);

    /* Removes the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to
     * the specified value. Not required for Lab 8. If you don't implement this,
     * throw an UnsupportedOperationException.*/
    V remove(K key, V value);
}

package lab8;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BSTMap<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Map61B<K,V> {

    Node root;
    int size;

    class Node{
        K key;
        V value;
        Node left,right; 

        public Node(){}

        public Node(K k,V v){
            key=k;
            value=v;
        }
    }

    public BSTMap(){}


    /** Removes all of the mappings from this map. */
    public void clear(){
        root=null;
        size=0;
    }

    /* Returns true if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. */
    public boolean containsKey(K key){
        return get(key) != null;
    }

    /* Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this
     * map contains no mapping for the key. 
     */
    public V get(K key){

        if(size()==0)
            return null;

        Node temp=root;
        //System.out.println("temp:"+temp+" "+temp.key);
        while(temp!=null){
            int comp=temp.key.compareTo(key);
            if(comp==0)
                return temp.value;
            else if(comp<0)
                temp=temp.left;
            else
                temp=temp.right;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map. */
    public int size(){
        return size;
    }


    //private recursive method
    private Node put(Node node,K key,V value){
        if(node==null)
            return new Node(key,value);
        int comp;
        comp=key.compareTo(node.key);
        if(comp==0)
            return node;
        else if(comp<0)
            node.left=put(node.left,key,value);
        else
            node.right=put(node.right,key,value);
        return node;
    }

    /* Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. */
    public void put(K key, V value){
        root=put(root,key,value);
        size++;
        return;
    }



    public void printInOrder(){
        if(size()==0){
            System.out.println("list empty");
            return;
        }
        inOrder(root);

    }

    private void printNode(Node node){
        System.out.print("("+node.key+" "+node.value+")");
    }

    private void inOrder(Node node){
        if(node==null)
            return;
        inOrder(node.left);
        printNode(node);
        inOrder(node.right);
    }

    private void inOrder(Node node,Set keySet){
        if(node==null)
            return ;
        inOrder(node.left,keySet);
        //System.out.println("Adding key:"+node.key);
        keySet.add(node.key);
        inOrder(node.right,keySet);
    }

    private void inOrder(Node node,K[] keys,int counter){
        if(node==null)
            return ;
        inOrder(node.left,keys,counter);
        System.out.println("Adding key to array at location:"+counter+" key:"+node.key);
        keys[counter++]=node.key;
        inOrder(node.right,keys,counter);
    }

    public Set<K> keySet(){
        if(root==null)
            return null;
        Set<K> keys=new HashSet<K>();
        inOrder(root,keys);
        return keys;
    }    

    public V remove(K key){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public V remove(K key, V value){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();  
    }

    public  class KeyIterator implements Iterator<K>{
        private K[] keys;
        private int counter;

        public KeyIterator(){
            keys=(K[])new Comparable[size];
            //(K[])new Comparable[size];
            inOrder(root,keys,counter);

            System.out.println("Printing inside constrcutor");
            for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
                System.out.print(keys[i]+" ");
            System.out.println();

        }

        public boolean hasNext(){
            return counter<keys.length;
        }

        public K next(){
            return keys[counter++];
        }
        public void remove(){

        }
    }

    public Iterator<K> iterator(){
        Iterator<K> seer=new KeyIterator();

        return seer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BSTMap<String, String> a = new BSTMap<String, String>();
        BSTMap<String, Integer> b = new BSTMap<String, Integer>();

        b.put("C", 1);
        System.out.println(b.get("C"));
        b.put("A", 2);
        b.put("B", 3);
        b.put("G", 4);
        b.printInOrder();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("keys are:"+b.keySet());

        System.out.println("Printing via enhanced for loop:");
        for(String str:b)
            System.out.println(str);

        //Above code is same as saying
        System.out.println("Printing the legendary iterator:");
        Iterator<String> seer=b.iterator();
        while(seer.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(seer.next());
        }

    }

}
```

The output is below

```
1
(A 2)(B 3)(C 1)(G 4)
keys are:[A, B, C, G]
Printing via enhanced for loop:
Adding key to array at location:0 key:A
Adding key to array at location:1 key:B
Adding key to array at location:0 key:C
Adding key to array at location:1 key:G
Printing inside constrcutor
C G null null
C
G
null
null
```

Comment: The code is incomplete and does not allow to replicate the problem.

Comment: Actually the code is very big so I thought of putting only the relevant code.

Comment: pushing the code on GitHub, will post the link in a minute

Comment: here is the link to code https://github.com/fsl4faisal/skeleton-sp16/blob/master/lab8/lab8/BSTMap.java -- I have changed the code at line 150 to-- keys=(K[])new Comparable[size]; and it seem to have suppressed the error but iterator is still not working, I am using the counter variable in inOrder() fn to save the items in the array, but the code is still buggy.

Comment: Thx for the code. Can you do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I ran the code from github and got no Exceptions.

Comment: @Vito that's because I changed it to-- keys=(K[])new Comparable[size]  mentioned in comments above. well' it still isn't working though

Comment: “isn’t working”, excuse me, it’s not a useable problem description. You need to edit the question to include precise observed behaviour.

Comment: @Ole actually I wasn't sure if I could do that, Thank you for making me clear, I will edit the question now

Comment: @Ole I have edited the question and shared my insight of why it isn't working

Comment: I see your problem with the `counter`variable. You need to have one such variable for the whole in-order traversal. I haven’t got a ready-made design proposal for it, though. There are some options.

Comment: I am open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an Array I used an ArrayList and it solved the problem.
The problem with the previous code was that the `counter` used to reset to 0 during the recursive call to `inOrder` since it was a local variable.
Changing it to array list eliminated the counter variable with `add()` function and it solved the problem
Below is the code for the same:-

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BSTMap<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Map61B<K,V> {

    Node root;
    int size;

    class Node{
        K key;
        V value;
        Node left,right,parent; 

        public Node(){}

        public Node(K k,V v,Node p){
            //System.out.println(k+" "+v+" "+p);
            key=k;
            value=v;
            parent=p;
        }
    }


    public class KeyIterator implements Iterator<K>{
        private ArrayList<K> keys;
        private int counter;

        public KeyIterator(){
            counter=0;
            keys=new ArrayList<K>();
            inOrder(root,keys);

            System.out.println("KeyIterator()");
            for(K k:keys)
                System.out.print(k+" ");
            System.out.println();

        }

        public boolean hasNext(){
            return counter<keys.size();
        }

        public K next(){
            return keys.get(counter++);
        }
        public void remove(){

        }
    }

    public Iterator<K> iterator(){
     Iterator<K> seer=new KeyIterator();

     return seer;
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
     BSTMap<String, String> a = new BSTMap<String, String>();
     BSTMap<String, Integer> b = new BSTMap<String, Integer>();

     b.put("H", 1);
     b.put("D", 2);
     b.put("I", 3);
     b.put("B", 4);
     b.put("E", 5);
     b.put("A", 6);
     b.put("C", 7);
     b.put("F", 7);
     b.put("G", 7);
     b.put("L", 7);
     b.put("I", 7);
     b.put("J", 7);
     b.put("N", 7);
     b.put("M", 7);
     b.put("O", 7);

     Iterator<String> seer=b.iterator();
     while(seer.hasNext()){
         System.out.println(seer.next());
     }

 }
}
```